# replacing linspace with meshgrid

Tags: matlab

I do a mistake by using meshgrid in a for loop. Let me give as an example the following code:

```
x=linspace(0,100,100);
y=linspace(0,100,100);
x0=[0 1 2 3];
y0=[4 5 6 7];
for i=1:4
   for j=1:length(x)
      for k=1:length(y)
         r(i,j,k)=sqrt((x(j)-x0(i)).^2+(y(k)-y0(i)).^2);
      end
   end
end
```

I think I unnecessarily utilize here for loops and try to replace it by meshgrid

```
[x,y]=meshgrid(0:1:100);
for i=1:4
   r(i,:,:)=sqrt((x(:)-x0(i)).^2+(y(:)-y0(i)).^2);
end
```

Could you please help me to rewrite this code?

Comment: I assume there is a typo in your original code: you loop `for k=1:length(y)` but index `y(j)`. Did you mean `y(k)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x=linspace(0,100,100);
```

First comment: this will not produce `[0 1 2 ... 100]` - for that you would use `linspace(0,100,101)` since there are 101 elements in `0:100`

You were actually very close to getting this right. Just don't turn `xx` into `xx(:)` (then the shape will be wrong at the end):

```
[xx yy] = meshgrid(0:100, 0:100); % I like to use xx and yy to remind myself they are 2d...

x0=[0 1 2 3];
y0=[4 5 6 7];
for ii=1:4 % I use ii since i is also used as a built in variable with value sqrt(-1)
    r(ii,:,:) = sqrt((xx - x0(ii)).^2 + (yy - y0(ii)).^2);
end
```

It is probably OK to leave the innermost for loop. I can't think of a way to get rid of it that wouldn't make your code less readable.

Comment: I've just run this code and it doesn't produce the same result as the original nested loops.

Comment: @EitanT - I believe there is almost certainly a typo in the original code - the index of `y` must surely be `k` and not `j`... But I agree with you.

Answer (score 4):

No loops no meshgrid - just have fun with `bsxfun`:

```
dx = bsxfun( @minus, linspace( 0, 100, 100 ), x0' ).^2; %//'
dy = bsxfun( @minus, linspace( 0, 100, 100 ), y0' ).^2; %//'
r = sqrt( bsxfun( @plus, permute( dx, [2 1 3] ), ...
                         permute( dy, [2 3 1] ) ) );
```

Voila!

Comment: +1: Just when I was about to write myself. `bsxfun` is on a roll in the past few days :)

Comment: @EitanT I'm just "flying" on `bsxfun` - added a [tag:bsxfun], you are more than welcome to contribute.

Comment: @EitanT - we had this discussion before with 'vectorization' tag. I believe I learned my lesson. As you can see I did not tag this question as 'bsxfun'.

Comment: @EitanT I tagged my "fun with `bsxfun`" question, though... ;-)

Comment: Ok. I'll remove my comments now to avoid cluttering the comments section.

Comment: @shai - thanks for reminding me of this alternative! "fun with bsxfun" - I will have to add it to my toolbox, and +1 for the reminder. Note the "probable bug" with the `linspace(0,100,100)` command (in OP original code) which `~=0:100` as I assume was intended.